# print model data in view page in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I have written the following code to print model data in view,
but it displays an empty view page. This is the controller code:

```
function new1()
{
     $user = JFactory::getUser();

     //assign the model
     $model = $this->getModel('add');

     $connect= $model->addJob(JRequest::get());

     $view = $this->getView('helloworld', 'html');

     $view->setLayout('new');
     $view->setModel($model,false);

     $view->display();
}
```

Comment: Please take more care with your grammar and wording. If your question is hard to read you won't get answers. I fixed that for you.